# Can we have an 'Update metadata' button in Image Gallery for all image instances?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, images, gallery

{Note: This question is a followup of [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179667/how-do-i-change-the-description-of-the-same-image-which-is-to-be-found-in-multip/).}

It is possible to implement the following:

In WP go to `Media | Library` and select an image. The `'Attachment Details'` window appear.

We have there in the right-bottom corner some buttons: `'View attachment page'`, `'Delete...'` etc.

It is possible to add there a new button called `'Update Metadata/Alt Text+Description for all instances'` ?

In fact it will work in the same manner with the normal save metadata procedure but **for all instances of the same image** (same URL/ID? - I'm not sure how WP 'knows' that there are siblings but it knows) just issue an SQL update against DB for all attachments with the same attachment URL (eg. mysite.com...\img001.jpg) or, better, parent(?) ID(?)

Comment: I think you're missing some knowledge of how media and attachments are represented in the database, and exactly how metadata is stored, they're posts of type `attachment`, and the meta data is just post meta, the same way custom fields are just post meta. WordPress doesn't refer to the file, it refers to the post. The UI you're asking about is a javascript based UI powered by backbone.js

Comment: @TomJNowell: Most probably. But speaking from architectural POV it is (IMHO) at least very problematic (if not broken): If I upload a single image this should be a *single* entity/object (image). For example, I uploaded an image, attached it in my Blog, Gallery/Portfolio and in my Wedding, Portrait and Journalism (etc. etc. etc.) slide-shows. After that I realize that I want to update it because I made a grammatical error, spelling or simply I want to add/edit/remove info to the caption(s). Why I cannot do this?

Comment: And more: In fact, the WP's database simply isn't normalized (a big DB architectural mistake) and the real life pushes me to find a solution for this.

Comment: It IS a single entity, it's a post of type attachment, everywhere else references the post ID, if you have the same image multiple times it's either because you uploaded it multiple times or you're using code that doesn't handle images correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the screen you're referring to:

[image: screenshot of the media screen]

That interface is a modal dialog created using javascript. Specifically, backbone.js. Internally WordPress stores files in the file system and creates a post for them of type `attachment`. This attachment post stores the title, caption and other information. Because of this, it's possible to have comments on an image, categories etc, in the same way that posts of type `page` and `post` do. In WordPress, the attachment posts ID is stored, not the file itself, e.g. a featured image is an attachment ID in post meta. This way we don't need multiple copies if the image appears in multiple places.

This means there is a full post edit screen for any image.

However because we have this screen, and it's powered by javascript, when you edit the fields, they're automatically saved. There is no need for an update/save button. As soon as you modify any field, it sends the update once the field looses focus or the enter key is pressed, showing a spinner then the word 'saved' in the corner:

[image: the saved message]

Clicking on edit more details also shows a full attachment post edit page with all of those fields and more, including an update button:

[image: the attachment edit screen]

If you really wanted to, you could add a button to submit the form using javascript, however, the code is undocumented, you'd need to disable the auto-saving, and the whole thing [might be changing in the future](https://make.wordpress.org/design/tag/image-flow/)