# How to get image ID to use inside wp_read_image_metadata()?

Tags: images, filters

I would like to automatically set the alternative text to be the same as the title of a post when image is uploaded. I have found this function which works good for setting caption.

For updating alt text I believe I need to use `update_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $post_title);` but how can I obtain image id? 
How can I even do var_dump() inside of this filter?

```
/**
 * Add the Media/Image filename to caption, Title
 *
 */
function wpsx_5505_modify_uploaded_file_meta($meta, $file, $sourceImageType) {

    // Get the parent post ID, if there is one
    if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
    } else {
        $post_id = false;
    }

    // Only do this if we got the post ID--otherwise they're probably in
    //  the media section rather than uploading an image from a post.
    if($post_id && is_numeric($post_id)) {

        // Get the post title
        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);

        // If we found a title
        if($post_title) {

            $meta['caption'] = $post_title;

        }

    }

    return $meta;

}
add_filter('wp_read_image_metadata', 'wpsx_5505_modify_uploaded_file_meta', 1, 3);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39683724/2769517

Comment: The prefix `wpsx_5505` gives away the original questions' number here on WPSE and here it is: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/rename-files-during-upload-using-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to automatically set the alternative text to be the same
>   as the title of a post when image is uploaded.

The attachment's image *alternative text* is stored in the post meta table under the `_wp_attachment_image_alt` meta key.

In [`media_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) and [`media_handle_sideload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/) we have:

```
$id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, $post_id);
if ( !is_wp_error($id) )
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $file ) );
```

The [`wp_insert_attachment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/) is a wrapper for [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) and the `add_attachment` is fired after the attachment has been written to the posts table.

**Example**

Here's a way to automatically set the alternative text as the attached parent post's *title*, during upload, through the `add_attachment` hook:

```
/**
 * Set the attachment image alt as the parent post's title, during upload
 */

add_action( 'add_attachment', function( $attachment_id )
{
    // Nothing to do if it's not an image
    if( ! wp_attachment_is_image( $attachment_id ) )
        return;

    // Get parent post's ID for the image
    $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $attachment_id );

    // Nothing to do if the image isn't attached to a post
    if( ! $parent_id )
        return;

    // Get parent post's title
    $parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id );

    // Nothing to do if the attached post has no title
    if( empty( $parent_title ) )
        return;

    // Set the image alt as the parent post's title
    update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $parent_title );

} );
```

**Notes**

Note that we don't want to add the `_wp_attachment_image_alt` key to all attachments, so that's why we use [`wp_attachment_is_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_attachment_is_image/) to only target the images.

We could also hook into [`wp_update_attachment_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_update_attachment_metadata/) or [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/)  in a similar way, where the attachment's ID passed on as the second filter input argument.

The [`wp_read_image_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_read_image_metadata/) is called within [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) to e.g. retrieve the EXIF and IPTC data. This is where OP is currently hooking into.

Also note that when the parent post title is changed, the alternative text goes out of sync. In a somewhat related question, I've discussed some options [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179689/26350).